# pass 2 int array to method and return 1 int array - java

Tags: java, arrays

how can I pass two int array to method and return one int array?

I wrote something like :

```
public class Temp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
//some code
       int[] a = new int[10];
       int[] b = new int[10];
//some code
       int[] c = rk (a , b);
    }

    public static int[] rk (int[] d , int[] e){
//some code
       int [] c = new int[10];
//some code
       return c;
    }
}
```

but it didn't work

Comment: If you dont post your full code how can we investigate why it doesnt work?

Comment: Are you missing some closing parentheses, or did you just forget to copy them to the question?

Comment: "It didn't work" doesn't tell us anything about what you expected to happen or what actually happened. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: You can't define methods inside other methods like this.

Comment: forgot to copy , actually stackoverflow didn't let me copy my full code because of few explain

Comment: The code you posted doesn't even compile, how would you expect it to work?

Comment: I have fixed the typos in your code, but I may have fixed the problem as well....

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `ArrayUtils` like this:

```
  int[] both = (int[])ArrayUtils.addAll(d, e);
```

If you cant use `ArrayUtils` try this:

```
   public int[] rk(int[] d , int[] e){
    int dLg = d.length;
    int eLg = e.length;
    int[] c = new int[dLg + eLg];
   System.arraycopy(d, 0, c, 0, dLg);
   System.arraycopy(e, 0, c, dLg, eLg);
  return c;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The method has to be static, unless you make an instance of the class with the method

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
public static int[] rk (int[] d , int[] e){
int aLen = d.length;
   int bLen = e.length;
   int[] c= new int[aLen+bLen];
   System.arraycopy(d, 0, c, 0, aLen);
   System.arraycopy(e, 0, c, aLen, bLen);
   return c;
}
```